# How to pipe data modified from a gunzip stream into a gzip stream?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I need to trigger, through an http request, a process where I download some data from S3, gunzip it, modify the stream, gzip it and send to another bucket in S3.

So far I was able to either:

1. Download
2. Gunzip
3. Modify (filter) the data
4. return the data

Or:

1. Download
2. Gunzip
3. Gzip
4. Upload the unmodified data and retrieve the url of the object

My first attempt at this consisted in using the *on('data')* event from the gunzip stream to modify the data; then when the 'end' event is thrown, I can return it to the browser making the request.

```
var accumulator = [];

gunzip.on('data', chunk=>{
    var lines = chunk.toString('utf-8').split(\n);
    lines.forEach(line=>{
       if(shouldBeFiltered(line)){
         accumulator.push(line);
       }
    })
})

gunzip.on('end', ()=>{
    res.send(accumulator);
})

getS3.pipe(gunzip)
```

If instead of returning the result (res.send) I try to pipe gunzip to gzip, the filter is ignored. It makes sense as I have an *accumulator* array that I return (in the previous case) when the end event is thrown.

Then after some digging, I found a reference suggesting that the data should be *pushed* to, and I tried the following, which did not work:

```
gunzip.on('data', chunk=>{
    var lines = chunk.toString('utf-8').split(\n);
    lines.forEach(line=>{
       if(shouldBeFiltered(line)){
         gunzip.push(line);
       }
    })
})

// the end event no longer mattered
// gunzip.on('end', ()=>{
//    res.send(accumulator);
// })

getS3.pipe(gunzip).pipe(gzip).pipe(putS3(putS3param.Key, putS3param.Bucket));
```

Then I tried to create a transform stream (this is extremely simplified as I was trying the concept), but then I had an internal error:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const Transform = stream.Transform;

function filter(pipeline) {
    var the_filter = new Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, next) {
            console.log();
            chunk += Buffer('Modified', 'utf-8');
            this.push(chunk);
            next();
        }
    });
    pipeline.pipe(the_filter);
}
```

Other than creating a file and gziping it and uploading I have no more ideas.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging around, I finally found the answer in this [page](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/practical-examples-of-the-new-node-js-streams-api/)

It seems that what was missing as setting Transform as **objectMode**, other than that, I see nothing relevant.

```
    var stream = require('stream')
    var liner = new stream.Transform( { objectMode: true } )
    
    liner._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
         var data = chunk.toString()
         if (this._lastLineData) data = this._lastLineData + data
    
         var lines = data.split('\n')
         this._lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length-1,1)[0]
    
         lines.forEach(this.push.bind(this))
         done()
    }
    
    liner._flush = function (done) {
         if (this._lastLineData) this.push(this._lastLineData)
         this._lastLineData = null
         done()
    }
    
    module.exports = liner
```